# Execute a script from the exec directory

Tags: r

In R packages [there can be a directory `exec`](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/misc.html) which contains some executable scripts. I have such a script called `json_merge.R` in my package `numericprojection`. This gets installed to `~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/numericprojection/exec/json_merge.R`.

To execute it I can of course specify that particular path and call it with `Rscript` from the command line. I was wondering whether there is some way to have R resolve this path such that I could just specify `json_merge.R` and `numericprojection`.

---

In the meantime I constructed this here:

```sh
r_libs_user="$(Rscript -e "cat(Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER'))")"                       
script="$r_libs_user/numericprojection/exec/projected_merge.R"                     
script="${script/#\~/$HOME}"  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485157/653152        

"$script"
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap `json_merge.R` in an internal or exported function?

Comment: As far as I understand the use of `exec` is discouraged and also the idea seems to be that you place scripts in other languages in this folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109815/5028841

Comment: Having a stand-alone script has the advantage that I can execute it line-by-line in RStudio. But actually I can do that with an argument-less function as well. And I can make all the utilities private. Yes, that makes more sense!

Comment: I answered it anyway since there is an easy enough way to do that. If `json_merge.R` is something you want to show the user, you could think about writing a vignette instead if the script. This way it's also easier to provide comments to what the script is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `system.file` command is for. In your case that command should look like this:

```
system.file("exec", "json_merge.R", package = "numericprojection")
```

And will return:

```
~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/numericprojection/exec/json_merge.R
```

If that is where the file was installed.

However, I think that your question is likely based on a misunderstanding as outlined in the comments.